# Confusing map function definition in Wadler's paper

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

Can someone please help me understand this map definition in Professor Wadler's original paper Monads for Functional Programming (Haskell).

```
map :: (a → b) →(M a →M b)     
map  f m =m >= λa.unit(f a)
```

I understand why it is declared as a morphism from f::a -> b to g::Ma -> Mb. Why is it confusingly defined as seemingly taking 2 args f and m. m is a computation ( function with side effects) that I assume can be defined as data or type.

Comment: Returning a function still leaves it's parameters available! `(a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)` does not leave `(m a -> m b)` opaque! This is the nature of currying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A definition of the form

```
foo x y z = bar
```

is equivalent to all of the following ones

```
foo x y = \z -> bar
foo x = \y z -> bar
foo = \x y z -> bar
```

Hence, the posted code could also be written as

```
map :: (a → b) → (M a → M b)     
map f = \m -> m >= \a -> unit (f a)
-- which is parsed as
-- map f = \m -> (m >= (\a -> (unit (f a))))
```

The above indeed emphasizes that `map` maps functions to functions, and is arguably clearer. However, it is a bit more verbose, so it is common in Haskell to move the arguments to the left side of `=` as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks . This clears my doubt . I have seen explanations that make no distinction between map being a mapper from a normal function to a monadic function. And map being a higher order function that takes a normal function and a (ex. list) monad. Can you please elaborate a bit on \m->m ? I am unsure how to read it .

Comment: @Asterisk I added all the parentheses to guide reading. Precedence can indeed be confusing here.

Comment: @Asterisk Part of the point of the way Haskell's syntax works is that you don't need to make a distinction between those two "ways of being" for `map`. They are in fact merely different points of view on *exactly the same concept*. Because they're exactly the same, you never have to worry about neglecting one of those interpretations; you can use whichever point of view has the least mental friction in the context you're working, even freely flip-flopping between them (as happened in your quoted example between the type signature and the implementation, which is indeed a little confusing).

Answer (score 4):

The second argument is the *first* argument for the *returned* function:

```
map : (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
map = \(f : a -> b) -> \(x : m a) ->
        x >>= (\a -> return (f a))
```

Comment: I seem to understand it a bit . It seems map ( higher order function) is applying  f to a generator over m a. Can you please explain the syntax a bit in English . Sorry I come from a imperative / oo background and still learning Haskell .

Comment: Sure!! It's actually far more simple. The two type signatures are the same:

    `map : (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b) ~
    map : (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`

This could be seen as `->` being "right-associative", basically saying that `x <> y <> z == x <> (y <> z)`. This is the nature of higher-order implication logic because supplying _part_ of the data to a prolonged execution should _return_ a prolonged execution (in the case that there's still more data needed), or just the data itself. In this scenario, prolonged executions are treated in the exact same way as data.

Comment: You should also take care to note that my usage of "prolonged execution" is _really_ sloppy - I'm not talking about strictness, thunks, or what normal-form is. This is strictly talking about functions - `a -> b` could be seen as a prolonged execution to the data of `b`, provided once we have `a` (sorry fellow haskellers for this botched explanation :\)

Comment: Also, `map f x == (map f) x`, if that make sense. That is, if `f : a -> b`, and `x : m a`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this !